# Why my spark application is too slow?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.6 version in StandAlone cluster mode and I have one master node and two worker nodes.
I have assigned 6 executors for my application and those executors are running on following nodes : -

```
on MasterNode : 2 executors(with 1gb RAM and 1 core for each executor)
on WorkerNode1 : 2 executors(with 1gb RAM and 1 core for each executor)
on WorkerNode2 : 2 executors(with 1gb RAM and 1 core for each executor)
```

And my application gets data from kafka and applies some logic on incoming data and then writes these records into Cassandra as a dataframe?

Please help me.
Thanks In Advance
sometimes it is taking too much time to initiate a job and data is continously being fetched from kafka and all the memory which is assigned to executors gets fully consumed. 
So is there any approach to speed up my spark application.

Comment: It is very hard to provide any insights unless you provide some sample data, code which you have tried

Comment: I think there is no issue in code because when I execute this code on Spark of DataStax then it is working fine and processing 6-7k records per second but when I switch to apache spark then it is not even start the job on executors.

Comment: The most probable problem is the apache-spark's cluster bad configuration. Retry your job submit with 4 executors on your workers and don't overload your master. You are working with kafka and cassandra and you have 2 executors on your master node too. Then I guess it may be the failure point of your cluster.

Comment: If you add more partitions to your Kafka topic, and add more Spark executors, it'll increase parallelism. Assuming the bottleneck is reading from Kafka, not your processing logic